# How do I google/search across StackExchange sites

Tags: support

Seems like this would be a common need, but I don't see a similar question.

I want to post a question, but am not sure of the correct forum.
So I want to search for similar questions.
Searching from one of the sites appears to return responses from that site only.

Comment: Each site also has a page at /help/on-topic that gives information about what the site expects. [SO's page for example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The search box on http://stackexchange.com will search across all sites.